# Model Factory association with existing models

Tags: php, laravel, model, factory

I have the following structure in my Laravel 5.2 app:

User:
id
name
...

Post:
id
title
body
user_id (fk)

Comment:
id
body
user_id (fk)
post_id (fk)

I want to create few users (20), for each users a random number of Posts, and to each post, a random number of comments(even a fixed number it`s ok).

I can create users and assign Posts to each, but i can't assign comments to each post:
i have this:

```
factory(App\User::class, 20)->create()->each(function($u) {
   $u->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 5)->make();
});
```

I found something but didn`t work:

```
factory(App\Comment::class, 100)->create()->each(function($u) {
   $u->user()->sync(
      App\User::all()->random(3)
   );
});
```

NOTE: i made the relationship between models like this:
User hasMany Post,
User hasMany Comment,
Post hasMany Comment,
Comment belongsTo Post,
Comment belongsTo User

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using your factories to nest your next child etc.

You have relationships which are referenced by some `fk` so to achieve correct 'fk' values you can do the following:

```
factory('App\Users', 123)->create()->each(function ($u) {

        factory('App\Posts', 1)->create([
            'user_id' => $u->id,
        ])->each(function ($e) use ($u) {
            factory('App\Comments', 10)->create([
                'user_id' => $u->id,
                'post_id' => $e->id,
            ]);
        });

    });
```

The arrays in the `create` method will override the values set in your `ModelFactory.php`

Comment: [ErrorException]
  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$orders

Comment: I changed to App\User::class and the error`s gone. :)) Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Well, this creates a couple of comments from the same user in his own posts. But I guess its OK for generic testing, to just populate a database with data.